# Show/Hide row visability from parameter

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a row on a table that's acting as a header row.  It can be displayed or not displayed using two diff parameters.  So far I have

```
=IIF(((InStr(join(Parameters!PRO.Value,", "),"-1") AND Parameters!ShowPro.Value="N")) ,true, false)
    or 
        IIF(((Instr(join(Parameters!PRO.value,","),"-1") and Parameters!ShowPro.value="Y")),false,true)
```

Basically saying If PRO value = -1 (select all) and ShowPro value = No (this parameter toggles a column) then hide row or the opposite happens.  Select all and ShowPro = Yes show row.  This works as intended as if the row is to be shown then the ReportItem PRO.value appears in this "header" row and there's a page break betwen each group displaying that groups PRO.value.

What I'm trying now is to add a third option if I don't select all (-1) but still want to display the row (ShowPro = "Y") then display the PRO.Values selected in this "header" row and each page break.  I've tried various forms of

```
IIF(not((Instr(join(Parameters!PRO.value,","),"-1") and Parameters!ShowPro.value="Y")),true,false)
```

and I just can't get it to work.  Any help greatly appreciated.  Hope I've explained it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue may be in the Or logic that is happening, and that you may wish to use nested iif statements instead. Right now, your code is evaluating both iif statements separately and returning a boolean (True/False) value for each. The statement will then simplify to

```
= True or False
```

which returns true or perhaps

```
= False or False
```

which returns false. Throw a third condition in there, and you may wind up with something like

```
= False or True or False
```

which would still evaluate to true, but may not be what you are looking for. Using nested iif statements would look like this:

```
=IIF(((InStr(join(Parameters!PRO.Value,", "),"-1") AND Parameters!ShowPro.Value="N")) ,true, IIF(((Instr(join(Parameters!PRO.value,","),"-1") and Parameters!ShowPro.value="Y")),false, IIF(not((Instr(join(Parameters!PRO.value,","),"-1") and Parameters!ShowPro.value="Y")),true,false)))
```

This evaluates each statement, and if it is true, returns the value specified. If it is false, it continues on to the next iif and evaluates that statement. Then, if the last iif statement is false, it will return false. You may need to tweak this answer to suit your purposes, but I think it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I went a different direction but you answered my original question, marking as an answer.